# Can't use security component on 404 pages?

Tags: symfony

I want my [custom error pages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) to use my main application base template. By base template uses `KnpMenu` to build a menu. Parts of the meny are only rendered for privileged users, and do to do that I inject the security component and do checks like this:

`if ($security->isGranted('ROLE_COURSES')) {`

However, when there's a 404 an exception is thrown in the routing component which is executed before the firewall component is run.

I'm not entirely sure what is actually injected into the menu builder since the security component has not yet run, but regardless, I'm getting another exception when I try to go to a non-existent page in production when that if statement is executed.

What's the recommended approach here? If I have to abandon rendering the menu for my 404's, I guess that's ok, but I was hoping I could still render the menu in its complete form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tonnes about this around the internet, it's related to the routing being loaded before the security context so when the route isn't found the user isn't even created.

A way to use it in your template is to use `{% if app.user is not null and is_granted() %}` as stated in https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/2078.

I assume that could be translated to

```
if (null !== $securityContext->getToken() && $securityContext->isGranted())
```

but I haven't tried it so I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually `$securityContext->getToken()` (made an edit to your answer). I just didn't know what exactly to check for that was equal to `app.user` in twig.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old issue, but facing this problem myself I fixed it by creating an extra route which matches everything and is the last thing to match of my routes:

```
pageNotFound:
    pattern:  /{path}
    defaults: { _controller: MyContentBundle:PageNotFound:pageNotFound, path: '' }
    requirements:
        path: .*
```

The action is simply:

```
public function pageNotFoundAction()
{
    throw new NotFoundHttpException();
}
```

Since you are throwing the NotFound exception from a controller, the firewall has already been run and you now have `app.user` in your custom 404 error page.